# Error in formatting in Namenode in hadoop

Tags: hadoop

i have installed hadoop , based on cygwin and windows. i have followed the steps from the site: http://ebiquity.umbc.edu/Tutorials/Hadoop/12%20-%20format%20the%20namendoe.html. but stucked at formatting namendoe.

This give me following error :

```
$ bin/hadoop namenode -format
14/02/01 15:29:59 INFO namenode.NameNode: STARTUP_MSG:
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting NameNode
STARTUP_MSG:   host = Satheesh/192.168.2.5
STARTUP_MSG:   args = [-format]
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 0.19.1
STARTUP_MSG:   build = https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/core/branches/bra                                                                                                                nch-0.19 -r 745977; compiled by 'ndaley' on Fri Feb 20 00:16:34 UTC 2009
************************************************************/
14/02/01 15:29:59 ERROR namenode.NameNode: java.io.IOException: javax.security.a                                                                                                                uth.login.LoginException: Login failed: Expect one token as the result of whoami                                                                                                                : satheesh\satheesh kumar
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UnixUserGroupInformation.login(UnixUserGro                                                                                                                upInformation.java:250)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UnixUserGroupInformation.login(UnixUserGro                                                                                                                upInformation.java:275)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UnixUserGroupInformation.login(UnixUserGro                                                                                                                upInformation.java:257)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.setConfigurationP                                                                                                                arameters(FSNamesystem.java:426)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.<init>(FSNamesyst                                                                                                                em.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.format(NameNode.java:                                                                                                                765)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNo                                                                                                                de.java:851)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:86                                                                                                                8)

        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.setConfigurationP                                                                                                                arameters(FSNamesystem.java:428)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.<init>(FSNamesyst                                                                                                                em.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.format(NameNode.java:                                                                                                                765)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNo                                                                                                                de.java:851)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:86                                                                                                                8)

14/02/01 15:29:59 INFO namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at Satheesh/192.168.2.5
************************************************************/
```

pls help me.

Comment: cygwin whoami is returning an unexpected format, instead of a single username it is getting "satheesh\satheesh kumar". That's probably related to your windows username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyway thnks , i finally got the solution , the configuration of cygwin is DOS command promt based so it doesnt accept space in user name. The space between name "Satheesh Kumar" does not accepts in my case. So i created a new user account and tried it again and got finally executed.

Answer (score 0):

Namenode is not formating because ssh is not working.

To check run this

```
ssh localhost
```

If it.prompt you for password you have to perform step for ssh login please see below link.

http://ebiquity.umbc.edu/Tutorials/Hadoop/05%20-%20Setup%20SSHD.html